# How to transfer credit history to another bank?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit, credit-history, bank-of-america

I am planing to make first credit card (BOA secured credit card).
Also, I want get UA explorer card later (I understand it is need high credit score).

I am trying to build credit history by this BOA secured. But Chase is another bank. So, actually where is my credit history will record?

P.S: I am USBANK customer. So, USBANK credit card is better than BOA secure for me I think. But USBANK is not offer FICO score. Is that true?

Comment: Your credit score is a composite of ALL credit cards, regardless of the issuer. Each issuer does not have its own "credit score" for you.

Comment: But I hear every bank have different credit score. So, not same at all.

Comment: you were either told wrong or misunderstood. There are three major credit reporting agencies, and most banks report to all 3.

Comment: OK. Because some website say "credit score is very slimier each bank. But not exactly same score they have." So do you know USBANK and BOA are reporting to all 3 credit agencies?

Comment: I would be shocked if they did not. They may not give you _access_ to FICO scores for free, but you can get them free through other means. That said, don't worry too much about your credit score. Pay your balances in full on time (so you don't pay interest), don't load your cards up too much, and your credit score will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have credit history so I think first credit card will be important to build credit score. If I pay my balance on time, I don't have any APR right? Also, I just find Deserve Edu credit card. How is it? I am student.

Comment: If you pay the _full_ balance on time, then you will not be charged any interest. Be careful not to overspend, though. Only use it for purchases that you could otherwise buy with cash (meaning don't use it to _borrow_ money)

Comment: Thank you for help!! I will think BOA secure or Deserve Edu credit card!!

Comment: Say no to secured cards.  As a student you are almost certainly eligible for a no-fee "student" credit card.  The bank makes more than enough money from M/C or VISA processing that they don't have to charge you, unless you have a bad credit history -- you shouldn't if you've never had credit before.  Also, freecreditscore.com (be careful to refuse the upsell) and you can see your FICO score and credit report free with updates every 30 days, it's not a trial that will cost you later.

Answer (score 1):

Credit scores are given based on credit reports these contains your credit history (Credit cards, loans, and in some places [monthly payments to contracts](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/loans/credit-rating-credit-score) (e.g. mobile contracts )

From your credit report compiled by the credit reference agencies (e.g. Experian and Equifax) and in addition to other information you provide on the application individual companies generate their own credit decisions based on their own rules. No-one knows theses rules exactly but an outline of some strategies can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_score_in_the_United_States) although companies can still chose their own. some companies may take into account opportunities to cross sell or other factors in addition to your credit history

Credit scores provided by reference agencies to individuals are therefore simply an indication of your likelihood to be accepted for credit by a generic company - in some cases an excellent credit history may even work against you.

Further US specific information can be found [here](https://www.usa.gov/credit-reports). Some information specific to the UK can be found [here](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/loans/credit-rating-credit-score)